# Complete if statement with strings and array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I have a page that has 3 variables.  They look like this:

```
String[] Headers = new String[] { "Max Width", "Max Length", "Max Height" };
String currentHeader = (String)HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ItemHas"] ?? "";
String checkString = (String)HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ItemIn"] ?? "";
```

The checkString is a list of Headers delimited by a "|".

What is the easiest way to check if my `currentHeader` is in my Headers array and in my checkString String?  I can do it but not in less than 20 lines of code.  That seems like a less than optimal solution.

Comment: I would consider using a HashSet<string> for your Headers, that way you will have a much better lookup time. If you only have a couple headers, it might not be worth it though...

Comment: I just have a few.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
checkString.Split('|').Contains(currentHeader) && Headers.Contains(currentHeader)
```

Using LINQ. Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentHeader) && Headers.Contains(currentHeader) && checkString.Split('|').Contains(currentHeader))
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a quick utility method:

```
private bool IsInHeader(string[] _headers, string _findme)
{
    if (_headers == null || _findme == null) return false;
    foreach (string s in _headers)
    {
        if (_findme == s) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And if _headers or _findme is null?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the line about the pipe-delimited string, but certainly you could modify the utility method to handle it. Also as Petoj suggested, the .Contains() method is concise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Headers.Contains(currentHeader) && checkString.Split('|').Contains(currentHeader)) {
    ....
}
```

And if you need it to be case-insensitive:

```
if (Headers.Contains(currentHeader, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
    && checkString.Split('|').Contains(currentHeader, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: +1 for culturally-sensative string comparisons! "Caf\u00E9" and "Cafe\u0301" look identical, they should compare as equal!

Comment: But I just read the code, and you have a serious bug. If `currentHeader` contains a value that is a substring of one of the other delimited values in `checkString`, then your check will incorrectly return true. Don't make me take my vote away, please!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but this should work:

```
var checks = checkString.Split('|');
if ( currentHeader.Contains(checkString) && Headers.Contains(checkString) )
{
   ....
}
```